# particles.js not covering entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles, particles.js

I'm trying to use [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) as background, but I am not able to set the canvas as a full-size background.

I tried at least 10 different solution from similar issues but nothing worked.
The canvas always results as as an element having width-height ratio as the screen but it doesn't cover it as a whole when it is resized.
In addiction, it won't set as background but as a child of the body, over or below the remaining elements.

I simplified the code as much as possible and the problem still persist.

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1xO1.png)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Try</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <div>
            <p>Something here</p>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="assets/js/particles.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
canvas{
  display:block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  position: absolute;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0;
}
```

APP.JS and PARTICLES.JS can be downloaded from the owner's website posted before.
I'm using themas they are at the moment

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I finally solved the background question:
That's how I managed it (I'm pretty sure I had already tried that but re-building the whole html if finally worked)

CSS

```
#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.body-particles{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- SOME CSSs HERE -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="assets/css/particles.css">

         <!-- SOME SCRIPTS HERE -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-particles">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- MY STUFF HERE, STYLED WITH MY CSS -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- particles.js container -->
        <div id="particles-js"></div>

        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/particles.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I have a new problem: being set as an underlying layer, it catch no pointer-events. As soon as I will make it works, I'll update the answer.

Obviously, feel free to help if you have any suggestion.

UPDATE: Workaround for mouseEvents: Adding class mouseEvents to elements I need to focus (for example , navbar, etc.)

CSS

```
.body-particles{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.mouseEvents{
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

However, it would be nice if someone knows a better way to keep events both in front and back layer

Comment: If you don't want to use particles js for the rest of your page, try `position: sticky;`

Answer (score 5):

I only had to do this...

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#particles-js {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to mimic the example page, what I would do is this:

```
body: {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

canvas{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.actual-content-container
{
   z-index: 100;
   /* whatever other style properties you want.  Apply this class to the div or other element you put your actual content in.*/
}
```

This is basically how the demo page is doing it.  The key is the z-index property.  If what you want is a background that scrolls with the actual content, try changing the position element of the particles-js id to absolute.  I think that should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: Still the same issue.. Already tried at least 30 different setups like this playing with positions, z-indexes and various properties but no-one fixes that. 
I always finish with the same result, also copying this css, applying your actual-content-container class and trying to modify it in some ways mainteining your overall idea :/

Comment: @NicolaZaltron: [Risa__B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8280885/risa-b) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16879239) changing `canvas` and `#particles-js` to use `width: 100vw; height: 100vh` instead of 100%. I am posting this because that user does not have [comment privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) yet.

Comment: @tom still the same, also using vw and vh was one of my first attempts but does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- Set positions fixed for #particles-js container

#particles-js{
   position:fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(52, 152, 219), rgb(44, 62, 80));
   background-repeat: repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

**- assigned class panel for the div having content in it.**

```
.panel{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 5%;
   margin-bottom: 5%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   left: 50;
   right: 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm probably too late here but this is how I solved having particles as a background was just a css fix

```css
#particles {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
}
```